# Working with two differents Jinja2 environments

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm making a Flask app. In some views I need to work with LaTeX templates instead of HTML.

It is posibble to create another Jinja2 environment and use the `render_template` function choosing the environment to use?

I'm using blueprints and I want to assign the templates folder in same way that I use the main Jinja environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jinja's `Environment.overlay` method to copy Flask's environment settings and then insert your own template loader to find template specific to a given blueprint (even if they share the name of a template elsewhere in the application).

```py
from jinja import ChoiceLoader

new_loader = ...
existing_loader = app.jinja_env.loader

new_environment = app.jinja_env.overlay(
            loader=ChoiceLoader([new_loader, existing_loader]),
            autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
            )
```

Here, I define a new template loader and insert it at the front of Jinja's lookup order. This retains all the rest of the Flask environment settings including variables like `request` and `app`.

Alternatively, you could wrap Flask's `render_template()` function and do the same thing. I've seen both approaches successfully deployed in production.